# Should templates, views, and models go in the Django config app?

Tags: python, django

Is it considered against Django "best practices" to place templates, views, or models inside the Django config app? (The same app with `settings.py`)

Templates are probably a "no" because template files in a `templates` directory under the config app will not be found by default, I had to add a `django.template.loaders.filesystem.Loader` to load them.

Thank you for any advice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> There’s no restriction that a project package can’t also be considered
>   an application and have models, etc. (which would require adding it to
>   INSTALLED_APPS).

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/applications/

Comment: Never saw that in the documentation. Thanks for pointing it out!

Answer (score 0):

Its normally a good practice to leave your project directory as such and keep the apps in their own separate directory and have them defined in the settings.py. This will make your project much more organised and easy to maintain.